# Mysql update statement for decimal fields to NULL or emptiness

Tags: mysql

Can't figure out, how to update decimal field to null or emptiness.

Have tried:

```
UPDATE ads SET price=NULL WHERE price=0
```

And

```
UPDATE ads SET price="" WHERE price=0
```

Isn't working.

Thanks ;)

(Update)
Just a moment.

Comment: can u show the create table statement?

Comment: Please post your table definition (at least for the field `price`). Does it allow `NULL`? Does any rows match the condition (`price = 0`)?

Comment: Yea rows did match. Aha, have set "ALLOW NULL" option, statement now works. Thanks :) Please add your answer so i could close the topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE ads SET price=NULL WHERE price=0
```

That is the correct way to set a field to NULL. However it will not work if the column does not allow NULL.

If you have the CREATE statement for that table available, check if it says NOT NULL for the price column.

If you don't have the CREATE statements you can run 'DESC ads' on oracle or mysql and see if NULL is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ads SET price=NULL WHERE price=0
```

Above statement will only work if you have allowed null values for column price.

AND

```
UPDATE ads SET price="" WHERE price=0
```

Above statement is not working because setting empty for decimal column is equivalent to set it to 0 value.

As the column already contains 0 value hence it might be giving 0 rows updated message.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with the answer of dsclementsen, that's why I upvoted him, but even if your price field can be NULL in your table definition, you might have constraints and triggers which prevent this update.

EDIT:

```
UPDATE ads SET price=NULL WHERE price=0
```

Did not work, because `price` was not nullable.

```
UPDATE ads SET price="" WHERE price=0
```

did not work, because:

- `price` is not textual
- you need to use `'` if you want to set a textual value