# How do I insert a NULL value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a `NULL` value into a table column containing the **phone area code** with the following properties:

```
mediumint unsigned DEFAULT NULL
```

In my PHP script, I have this check to convert an empty string to a `NULL` value:

```
if($_POST['area_code'] == "") $_POST['area_code'] = NULL;

// clean POST

foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
{
 $string[] = $field."=".$value;
}
$sql = "UPDATE Buyer SET ".implode(", ", $string)." WHERE user='$user'";
```

However, I am getting `0` instead of `NULL` value. What should I do to insert a `NULL`?

Comment: Please improve your implode(", ",$string) function.

Comment: Ouch! Unless this is never released to the Internet you should probably read up on SQL injection vulnerabilities. On topic: Set the `NULL` as a string (it will be a regular `NULL` when the query is executed): `$_POST['area_code'] = 'NULL';`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700239/mysql-update-statement-for-decimal-fields-to-null-or-emptiness

Comment: yes, i forgot to change that. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement needs to look like

```
UPDATE ... SET area_code = NULL ...
```

If you're casting a PHP `null` to a string as you do, it'll just cast to `""`, i.e. an empty string. You'll need to change the value to `"NULL"` (the string "NULL") instead of just `NULL` (the type `null`). You should also seriously escape/sanitize/validate your values before you plug them into an SQL query, you're wide open for SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Same as what Alain mentioned. I did apply a `mysqli_real_escape_string` to clean my `POST`. Not showing everything here. :)

Answer (score 3):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> **NULL is always converted to an empty string.**

when you build `$string[]`, you can't just concatenate your `$value`, or your nulls will be converted to empty strings, which convert back to zero. You'll have to do a test like:

```
$value == '' ? 'NULL' : $value
```

Comment: I don't want to make all empty string as `NULL` value. But I see your point why it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change PHP NULL to MySQL NULL(string):

```
if($_POST['area_code'] == '') $_POST['area_code'] = 'NULL';
```

Answer (score 2):

NULL is always converted to an empty string.

Try

```
if($_POST['area_code'] == "") $_POST['area_code'] = "NULL";
```

because null isn't a string

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
if($_POST['area_code'] == "") $_POST['area_code'] = "NULL";
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you cast your `NULL` to string:

```
$field."=".$value
```

You have two alternatives:

1. Code an exception for NULL values:

   ```
   if( is_null($value) ){
       $string[] = $field . '=NULL';
   }else{
       // Please note I've also added proper string escaping
       $string[] = $field . "='" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
   }
   ```
2. Switch to a library that supports prepared statements (IMHO, the simplest and most reliable solution):

   ```
   $string[] = $field . '=?';
   $params[] = $value;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should be escaping these posted values (maybe you already are). Secondly, `NULL` in PHP is always converted to an empty string (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Instead, use:

```
$_POST['area_code'] = 'NULL';
```

Which will then correctly create the string:

```
area_code=NULL
```

for your `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If your database table column data type is defined as int/float/numeric then it takes 0 instead of NULL. Because what you are doing is, making it as string that does not matches with column definition which was int/float.